# Laravel: checking two columns if one matches display the result

Tags: laravel

```
    $locationId=Auth::user()->location_id;
    $parcelDetails = $this->model
        ->whereBetween('date',array($fromDate, $toDate))
        ->where('source_from',$locationId)
        ->orWhere('destination_to',$locationId)
        ->with('sourceFrom', 'destinationTo')
        ->paginate($perPage);
        //get();
    return $parcelDetails;
```

i want to get the results where my source_from or destination_to matches $locationId with the dates given.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [nested where](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres) to accomplish that:

```
$locationId=Auth::user()->location_id;
$parcelDetails = $this->model
    ->whereBetween('date',array($fromDate, $toDate))
    ->where(function($q){
        $q->where('source_from', $locationId);
        $q->orWhere('destination_to', $locationId);
    })
    ->with('sourceFrom', 'destinationTo')
    ->paginate($perPage);
    //get();
return $parcelDetails;
```